# Licence management in salesforce app exchange

Tags: licenses

i had uploaded a managed package to salesforce apexchange,i had given Expire trail will be unlimited, but in customers org after installing the package,it is showing unlimited,but after 15 days package is expired,iam not able to get,what is the issue.please help me out.thanks in advance.

Comment: I was told once that no matter what you set your package to be it would install in a sandbox as a trial. not sure if that is still valid or not.

Comment: sorry ,,iam not able to understand,can u please elaborate .